# How to export paragraph styles in Pages?

Tags: pages, preferences, formatting

Here for example are four Paragraph Styles I often use:

[image]

Notice I have them all set up nicely, even with the F-key.

My remote colleague was working on a similar document. I wanted to say to her "Here, please take these, and use them it will be easier".

Similarly I often want to "take" those from my document, and "add them to" another document I have before me.

How is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no mechanism to export paragraph styles to another document in Pages.

Perhaps the most convenient way is to duplicate an existing document with the styles and shortcuts you wish to communicate, empty the duplicate, and send the empty document to your colleague so that she can fill it out as she needs.

If you are using the same styles and shortcuts in many of your Pages documents and creating new documents frequently, you might want to look into using templates if you are not already doing so. See the "[Create and use page templates in Pages on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/pages/page-templates-tan1959e234e/12.2/mac/1.0)
" Apple support webpage for details.

You can also copy a style and paste it to another document using the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, respectively, but that would only modify an existing style in the other document rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent and clear answer!  So, it can't be done.  TY